# Media Player Pause Button

Tags: kivy, kivymd

Good day friends.
I am new in kivy and kivymd. I am coding  for an audio media player using kivy and kivymd. The play button works well but the pause button is where my challenge is. I checked the kivy documentation but no way. I need your assistance guys. Below is the code.

.KV File:

```
MDIconButton:
            id: pla
            icon: 'play-outline'
            opacity: 1
            on_press: root.play()
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            MDIconButton:
                id: pau
                icon: 'pause'
                opacity: 0
                on_press: root.on_pause()
```

.PYFile:

```
def play(self):

    self.sound = SoundLoader.load('1Republic -2late 2 apologise.mp3')
    self.sound.play()

def on_pause(self):
    self.sound.pause()
```

Comment: Try using `stop()` instead of `pause()`.

Comment: Thank you @john anderson. But stop is different from pause. With stop, the song stops entirely and when played, it starts from the beginning but when paused, it stops at a particular spot/position and when played/resume, it continues from where it previously stopped. If i am to use stop(), how do i use it to pin it at a particular spot/position?

Answer (score 0):

The `kivy.core.audio.Sound` has some strange quirks. First, there is no `pause()` method, so you must implement that method yourself. You can implement that capability using `get_pos()`, `seek()`, `stop()` and `play()`. Another quirk is that the `seek()` only works after calling `play()`, and there must be a delay between calling `play()` and calling `seek()`.

Here is an example code that implements a `pause` capability:

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout

kv = '''
Player:
    MDIconButton:
        id: pla
        icon: 'play-outline'
        on_press: root.play()
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDIconButton:
            id: pau
            icon: 'pause'
            on_press: root.pause()
        MDIconButton:
            id: res
            icon: 'cog-play'
            on_press: root.resume()
'''


class Player(MDBoxLayout):

    def play(self):
        self.sound = SoundLoader.load('1Republic -2late 2 apologise.mp3')
        self.sound_pos = 0
        self.sound.play()

    def pause(self):
        self.sound_pos = self.sound.get_pos()
        self.sound.stop()

    def resume(self):
        self.sound.play()
        Clock.schedule_once(self.do_seek)  # seems to be required to get seek to work

    def do_seek(self, dt):
        self.sound.seek(self.sound_pos)

class TestApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


TestApp().run()
```

Comment: thanks @john anderson. Will give it a try and work around it